# How can you extend a theme without modifying the theme from shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I need to make many updates to a theme in shopify, without touching the theme's code in shopify.

In wordpress it would be like using a theme child. Another similarity would be like "extending" classes, but in this case, I need to modify functionalities from a theme (add, remove and change).

Many things can be required. Style changes, behaviors, etc.

Also it is not one thing, but it is something that will be changing constantly through months/years.

But the theme itself should not be changed at all (by me).

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the theme as .zip, re-upload it to your store and modify that.

If you expect to do many changes, unzip and upload the theme to github, and connect it to Shopify, modify it from there.

That's your best bet, nothing like modifying code without touching the theme's code in shopify.

What I do for small changes is wrap old theme code in `{% comment %}` and `{% endcomment %}` blocks, so I still keep old code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know what you are trying to say. But the problem is not modifying the theme itself.

The issue is that we are customizing a third party theme, but then we need to merge their updates into our changes. So to avoid this issue, we want to separate our changes from their code. 

We do have a repository with a special branch that only contains their changes, and other branches where we make our updates and merge their updates to ours.

But this is becoming a huge issue if we need to make changes in specific parts of the code, and then they completely change the file.

Comment: For example I have made many changes to a product card. And then the theme completely changes how it works. This would not be an issue if that is all that's changed. Now say that 5 months later you have so many changes that the original theme and your theme are different in many areas. How can you merge them? You basically have to completely separate yourself from the theme, and can't use any of their updates.